# Regex to check whether string has a decimal and two integers at the end

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can someone help me build a Regex that will check whether a string with only numbers and a decimal contains a decimal and then two integers 0-9 at the end?

So that something like the following would pass

3423.32
35232.53

but not 
3223
232
232 
asfas
232.3
232.3432
232.222

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\d+\.\d\d$/
```

should do.

- `^` start of the string
- `\d+` selects any amount (actually 1 or more) of number characters
- `\.` the actual '.' character, but because `.` normally is special in regular expression, it needs the `\`
- `\d\d` two numbers
- `$` end of the string

You can always put a regular expression into https://regexr.com/ to see a similar explanation :)

Comment: I am getting false for test value such as 200.00 which should return true

Comment: @DannyJ. `/^\d+\.\d\d$/.test('200.00')` returns true in my console, you might be testing with a number instead of a string? `/^\d+\.\d\d$/.test(200.00)` will return false, because `200.00` is a number (and will be saved as just `200`), `"200.00"` is a string :) What is the code that didn't work for you?